# Best puzzles of 2018 Q3 (July - September)?

Tags: discussion, best-of

*This question is part of the [best-puzzle award series](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of).*

---

> ### What are your nominations for the best puzzles, here on Puzzling.SE, of the third quarter (July / August / September) 2018?

Suggested guidelines for nomination:

- Nominate each individual puzzle in a separate answer, so they can be upvoted/downvoted separately.
- No more than 3 nominations per person.
- Don't nominate your own puzzles.
- Before you nominate a puzzle, check to see if someone else has already nominated it. If they have, then add to that nomination as a comment (or edit it) instead of nominating the same puzzle again.
- **In your nomination, explain what it is that (in your opinion) makes the nominated puzzle such a good one.**

---

> Some lists to help jog your memory (your nomination doesn't have to be from these lists):
>
> - Algorithmically selected "best of":
>
>   - [***Popular puzzles***, both in score and in vote to view ratio, from 2018 Q3](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/509699/popular-puzzles-quaterly?year=2018&month=07#query-results)
>   - [Well received puzzles ***you may have missed*** from 2018 Q3](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/871694/puzzles-you-may-have-missed-quaterly?year=2018&month=07#query-results)
> - Best by votes/views:
>
>   - [Questions with the most ***votes*** from 2018 Q3](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106579?StartDate=2018/07/01#query-results)
>   - [Questions with the most ***views*** from 2018 Q3](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106705?StartDate=2018/07/01#query-results)
>   - [Questions with the highest-voted ***answers*** from 2018 Q3](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106709?StartDate=2018/07/01#query-results)

---

<sub>Meta-meta issues:</sub>

- <sub>Is this kind of thing allowed on SE?</sub>

  - <sub>Yes, [Photography SE](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest) and [Sci-fi/Fantasy SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3142/31394) do something very similar.</sub>
- <sub>What's the point?</sub>

  - <sub>To highlight and encourage good practice in a way that goes beyond upvotes.</sub>
  - <sub>To work towards building a 'hall of fame' of some of the best puzzles on the site (perhaps to reside on a future puzzling.SE blog) - think of it as our 'greatest hits album'.</sub>
  - <sub>To prompt members to put forward their own reflections on what makes a high-quality puzzle.</sub>